# Show this Riemann sum convergence

Tags: real-analysis, integration, self-learning, riemann-sum

Let $f$ be a polynomial of degree at most 1 and denote by $I$ the indicator function. For any $c>0$, how can I show that
$$\int_0^1 f^2(y)I(\lvert y\rvert\leq c)dy=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n f^2(i/n)I(\lvert i/n\rvert\leq c)?$$

I proved a similar result when the integrand was Lipschitz continuous. In this case, it can be discontinuous (depending on $c$). I struggling to find the right argument.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g(y)=(f(y))^{2}\chi_{|y|\leq c}$, so $g$ is Riemann integrable, as it is a product to two Riemann integrable functions, which are $f^{2}$ and $\chi_{|y|\leq c}$. Now the right-sided is just a Riemann sum of $g$ with uniform partition of $[0,1]$ with width $1/n$ and taking the right endpoint grids.

Comment: So you checked that the function $g$ is Riemann integrable, and just use the definition of Riemann integral as the limit of Riemann sums?

Comment: Yes, exactly, so there is no need to examine this very special case.